# Getting no data from database

Tags: php, sql

I'm attempting to develop a login system for a school project, but i ran into the bug and i don't know how to fix it.

On my Database, i have the password `spy123` stored in a sha256 hash, but when i try to grab it in the php i get nothing in return.

Current code:

```
// checks if the user/password combination works.
// $username | String - the username of the user to login
// $password | 32byteHash - the hashed password of the user
// return | Boolean - Returns true if the password works for that user.
function forumLib_checkLogin($username, $password){
    $goodLogin = false; //Assume the password is wrong.

    $obtainUserPassword_query = "SELECT password FROM forum_users WHERE username = '$username'";

    $dbc = forumLib_connectToDB();
    $results = mysqli_query($dbc, $obtainUserPassword_query);
    forumLib_closeConnectionToDB($dbc);

    echo "query: $obtainUserPassword_query <br />";
    echo "results: ".mysqli_fetch_array($results)."<br />";
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
    echo "row[0]: ".$row[0]."<br />";
    echo "password: $password <br />";
    echo "DBpassword: $passwordOnDB <br />";

    //if user exists
    if($results != false){
        //get password from DB
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
        $passwordOnDB = $row['password'];

        //check password
        if($password == $passwordOnDB){
            //successfull login
            $goodLogin = false;
        }
    }

    return $goodLogin;
}
```

output:

```
change password request detected 
query: SELECT password FROM forum_users WHERE username = 'SpyMaster356' 
results: Array
row[0]: 
password: 7d9519224964c72a90b342c565fab1e4582d0e974043798f940b471304db0e24 
DBpassword:
Current password does not match records.
```

The sql query is not wrong as i get `7d9519224964c72a90b342c565fab1e4582d0e974043798f940b471304db0e24` back when i manually enter it.

This is really confusing me.

Comment: instead of echo use print_r($row) to see what's really being pulled from the database. You should also test the return value of the call to mysqli_query() to see if it's failed

Comment: With each execution of `mysqli_fetch_array`, your cursor inside the resultset gets incremented.

Comment: Also, the output `7d9519224964c72a90b342c565fab1e4582d0e974043798f940b471304db0e24` is not generated by the query; it is generated by the `$password` supplied to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have made the first call to `mysqli_fetch_array` you have consumed the first row of data.  Subsequently when you try to capture it into the `$row` variable, the row was already consumed and not saved:

```
// Prints  'Array'. Did not save the result
echo "results: ".mysqli_fetch_array($results)."<br />";

// Doesn't get anything because the row has been previously fetched
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
```

Comment: Ah let met see if that'll fix it then

Comment: It did. I found out what the real problem was. `//check password
        if($password == $passwordOnDB){
            //successfull login
            $goodLogin = false; //<--- NO. it should be true. DOPE
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Change the follwing segement

```
echo "query: $obtainUserPassword_query <br />";
echo "results: ".mysqli_fetch_array($results)."<br />";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
echo "row[0]: ".$row[0]."<br />";
echo "password: $password <br />";
echo "DBpassword: $passwordOnDB <br />";
```

to first populate the `$row` array, and using it for further `echo`.

```
echo "query: $obtainUserPassword_query <br />";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
echo "results: ". print_r($row) ."<br />";
echo "row[0]: ".$row[0]."<br />";
echo "password: $password <br />";
echo "DBpassword: {$row[0]} <br />";
```